# Создать структуру данных С++ как словарь в Python

Tags: c++, qt5

Что то подобное

```
 slave = [
{
address: 0,
value:0,
description:'description',
},
{
address: 0,
value:0,
description:'description',
}
]
```

Comment: Попытка перетаскивания практики программирования с языка A на язык B приводит к плохим последствиям в 4 случаях из 5. Так что в такой постановке вопрос похож на [проблему X-Y](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy), и с ним нужно разбиратся, как с проблемой X-Y, а именно - вам стоит рассказать нам, какую задачу вы изначально решаете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct smth
{
  int address;
  int value;
  std::string description;
};

std::vector<smth> slave;
```

Comment: Ну, либо std::variant

Comment: variant? хм, может все таки any ? Ответ в целом норм, вот только скорее всего автор вопроса хотел ещё увидеть, как это инициализировать. Но это такое.